# Remote UDP send and receive

Tags: c#, udp, client-server

Im trying to create a server/client application that will work on two or more remote computers with no local network between them.
So i searched the internet and find a TON and TONES of C# UDP client/server examples just like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx).

BUT i didn't find anywhere how to send a UDP socket over the internet on remote computer with, lets say IP="130.204.159.205";

please with your answers give me some example code

Comment: Sending files over UDP isn't much different from TCP. The port you use has to be open on the receiving computer, and an application listening to that port ready to perform action on data received.

Comment: If you have a cable/ADSL/DSL router it could be you are using [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which means the IP address your computer has is not accessible via the internet. If this is true you will need to configure your router to allow the UDP traffic through on the port of your choice. (Also some operating systems [restrict the ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_known_ports#Well-known_ports) a regular user account may use to avoid malicious software from stealing well known ports.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you linked shows [how to create the socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7.aspx), just remove the line `IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName())` and put use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx) and pass in a byte array with your ip address 130.204.159.205

```
(...)
// Connect to a remote device.
try {
    // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
    // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.
    IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 130, 204, 159, 205});
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,11000);
(...)
```